How to remove tyre dust caps
I have a flat tyre and want to fix the puncture.  I went to remove the nuts .  At first I thought I had the wrong locknut.
.
Then I realised they are the dust caps.  None of my star screw heads are big enough.  How do I remove dust caps (Volkswagen Touran 2015)

You might want to replace the centre cap to keep dust and water out.

@AndrewMorton thanks, didn't even realise it was missing!

Volkswagen provided a small tool made of wire. It should have a loop on one end and a 90° hook on the other. My Jetta had it in the trunk (boot, whatever) with the spare tire. You put the hook in the hole and pull the cap out. If the tool is no longer there, anything which is like it can be used. Also, they are not expensive to pick up a replacement.


thanks! really surprised, they just come off without screwing. I winder why they don't fall off when driving?
